# itertools product of python dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a Python dictionary with strings as keys and numpy arrays as values:

```
dictionary = {'first': np.array([1, 2]), 'second': np.array([3, 4])}
```

Now I want to use the `itertools` `product` to create the following list:

```
requested = [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

As normally done when the items passed to `product` are numpy arrays.

When I do the following:

```
list(product(list(dictionary.values())))
```

I get the following output instead:

```
[(array([3, 4]),), (array([1, 2]),)]
```

Comment: Unpack the dictionary values: `list(product(*dictionary.values()))`

Comment: That solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [*itertools.product()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function expects the arguments to be unpacked into separate arguments rather than kept in a single mapping view.  Use the [`*` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to do the unpacking:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from itertools import product
>>> dictionary = {'first': np.array([1, 2]), 'second': np.array([3, 4])}
>>> list(product(*dictionary.values()))
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```